# Selenium + Headless Chrome + JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `2.33` chrome driver and trying to access variable defined in HTML as `<script>var foo = "bar";</script>` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver_path = '<path>'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=driver_path)
driver.get("<url>")
driver.execute_script("return window.foo")
```

and it works fine. However, if uncomment `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")`, then, it returns `None` (and if I try to return `$` it throws `unknown error: $ is not defined`).

Why using headless mode influences the results in a such a way?

Comment: maybe this can help you to go around your problem: https://gist.github.com/anandsunderraman/e351485319a8a0e7df7e

Comment: OMG, I found an error in my initial question. If "--headless" is enabled, then I get errors and strange behaviour. When it is not, it is OK, but I want to run headless.

Comment: You should always make sure to set the user-agent as many sites end up blocking headless chrome, and it can be a real mind bender like what happened to me, carving up 2 days of my time.

The solution was to set the user-agent. I set it like:

    options.add_arguments(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

Where user_agent was dynamically set. See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69464060/1871891